# Is Angularjs $q resolve reject slowing down my web application more than standard callbacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, callback

im creating a web-app right now, using angularjs in combination with a php backend. Actually i have to admit, that i seem to use angulars $q(resolve reject) and their promises much too often, even in synchronous actions. So while communicating between controllers and services i'd like to know if i should instead replace them with simple callback functions? Or can i just return the result from the service to the controller when the promise is already passed from the $http to allow the time difference of that server request?

in fact i see that my web-app is scripting almost 3 seconds when larger content is requested via ajax. this is far too long. So can anyone tell me if this could be part of my performance issue or how to do this accurately in case of performance optimization?

Greets Julez

Comment: I wouldn't expect a Promise library to be your bottleneck when your talking about ajax in the same sentence.   Promises do have an overhead,  but you would have to be creating a lot of them for a 3 second performance hit.

Comment: i guess the chrome devtools performance test includes the request time of ajax requests as scripting time. To specialize the question, in theory .. when use my controller to call a function from the service that requests the server, the service and the controller do have to wait for the result.  Service awaiting the server response while controller awaits the service function result?Do i have to return the promise in both functions now, or only one, where the actual time delay happens?

Comment: In our application what we do is, if we are fetching data for an id, say like '/tendering/details/123', we create a fake promise, save the defer object in a map in our factory and return the promise to the controller. When the promise is resolved, we get the defer object from the map and resolve/reject it manually.

Comment: The $q service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Digest cycles can take time depending on how many watchers are attached to the DOM. I wonder why you are creating promises in synchronous code. It is going to add the needless overhead of extra digest cycles.

Comment: Okay, thats what i've feared. So i got quite a few watchers... in a forum there are topics and replies added with one time binding. Seems like i need to replace a lot of $q functions i was using. So instead should i now replace them with a callback, that gets passed to the service?  @user6083264  - what are fake promises?

Comment: the platform itself is not public yet, but i already created a testing version on my server. My experience with Javascript and PHP sums up to about two years, so i'm a beginner. But im quite happy that this app even works. A lot of code, but my files are all included to one and is visible here: [epTheme.js](http://ep-cdn.net/eptheme/eptheme.js.php)

Comment: By "fake" promise, I meant we dont just wait for the http call to end, we create a promise object, save the defer object and send back the promise object from factory to controller. and when the call ends we resolve it with the response manually.